# how to install the software which name can't be read on win7 english version?

Tags: windows-7, installation

There is a software which can only be installed on A Windows 7 chinese installation.

The following error happened when I attempted install it in on a Windows 7 English installation.  How do I install this software?

[image]

This isn't caused by a virus.

[image]

When I translated the directory to English, the program was, able to be installed.
How do I keep the name of the directory in chinese?

Changing the name of the directory to English is not solution I can actually implement.

Comment: Just right click on the setup and choose run as administrator. I think it will work

Comment: i have tried it ,the same error.

Comment: What is the software? I can't see the image very well (sorry). Maybe the software is only designed to work for certain licenses, locations, languages etc

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried copying the setup file to another, non-chinese folder? What happens then?

Comment: When i change all the name of directory into english, it can be installed successfully. what if i keep the chinese as the name of directory?I can not change all my directory into english.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature - The simple solution install the Chinese  language pack.  Once its installed you should be able to install it.

Comment: It looks like the program you're trying to install is not Unicode-aware. If you frequently need to install/run programs like that, you could open the Control Panel and go to **Clock, Language, and Region > Region and Language**. Once there, select the **Administrative** tab and change the system locale for non-Unicode programs. You'll need to restart Windows to apply the changes. Either way, installing a language pack and then changing the display language won't help.

Comment: it works for me when doing as you say.

Comment: @DaveRook If you right click -> Open Image in New Tab, you can view the full resolution version of the images on StackExchange websites.

Comment: http://users.wfu.edu/yipcw/atg/microsoft/applocale/

Answer (score -1):

I have figured out the solution. The Problem is is because of some special characters in the directory name added mistakenly from the download source or any other source (You can’t name your folder by using those characters, windows will automatically prohibit your action).

Suppose, you have a ‘**.exe**’ file in a  folder naming `?Ayodhya`. If you try to run that file, it will show the error most probably. So, all you have to do here is to change the folder name.

e.g : Change the folder Name in the way suggested below and I am sure that it will work.

```
Computer > Local Disk (E:) > Power2Go > SetUp
```

Comment: no . please see attachment in my post.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature I have updated the answer. Check if you still have problem.